# Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'case'

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I'm using two MySQL servers in the versions of MySQL SERVER 5.5 and MySQL SERVER 5.0. I try to execute a query in both the servers. This is my query:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `get_user_permissionlist`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_user_permissionlist`(
 pUserId INT,
 pApplicationId INT
)
BEGIN
DECLARE vDefaultManagerPermission VARCHAR(20);
SET vDefaultManagerPermission = (SELECT PermissionName FROM permission_level WHERE userid = pUserId);
IF vDefaultManagerPermission = 'Administrator'
THEN
    SELECT  PermissionId
           ,PermissionName
    FROM    ( SELECT    pl.PermissionId
               ,pl.PermissionName
               ,CASE permissionname
                  WHEN 'administrator' THEN '1'
                  WHEN 'operator' THEN '2'
                  WHEN 'power user' THEN '3'
                  ELSE '4'
                END AS rank
          FROM      permission_level pl
          WHERE     pl.ApplicationId = pApplicationId
        ) d
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN rank <= 3 THEN rank
              ELSE PermissionName
         END;
END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I try to executr the PROCEDURE usingthe following query.

```
CALL st_proc_get_user_permissionlist('5', '1')
```

When I execute the query in MySQL SERVER 5.0, there is no problem. But I try the same in MySQL SERVER 5.5 it shows the error:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'case'
```

I can't understand why it throws the error, and the Charset, Collation are same in both servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you started with different *default* collations on the two servers.  Let's debug it from two directions.

- When running the query, do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` from the same connection.  This may check the "character set" of the literals in the query.
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table on each server.  This should determine the character set for the fields such as `PermissionName`.

See if [bug 41627](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41627) applies, although it was 'fixed' in 5.1.34.

No `VIEW` is involved, correct?

This is really strange:

```
ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN rank <= 3 THEN rank
              ELSE PermissionName
         END;
```

`rank` is set to strings `1`, `2`, etc., then compared to the number "3", and finally sorted with `PermissionName`, which seems to be strings.  I don't know if this is the `CASE` that is causing trouble, but I recommend (for my sanity) that you not mix numbers and strings.

You can get rid of the other CASE:

```
WHERE PermissionName = CASE WHEN ApplicationId = 4
           THEN 'administrator'
           ELSE PermissionName END
```

by rewriting it as

```
WHERE ( PermissionName = 'administrator' OR ApplicationId != 4 )
```

**Edit**

Because of the strange combination of values, please try

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN 0+rank <= 3 THEN CONCAT(_utf8 '', rank)
          ELSE CONVERT(PermissionName USING utf8)
     END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rick James. Now i edit my question and give the entire procedure. Can you give me the solution.

Comment: Already I try the SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';. All the character sets are same in both of the Server versions.

Comment: added something else to try.

Comment: See the change (Edit) to ORDER BY in my Answer.